# Getting total duration and distance on MapBox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qt, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using MapBox GL API for Qt (JavaScript), and I have to get the total distance and total duration from a route. To obtain the route, I'm making the following http request:

https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-8.61767353533753,42.102184359031504;-8.495246688170312,41.44289308091726?steps=true&geometries=geojson&access_token=myToken

The response is in geoJSON format, which I use to draw the route on my map, and it works.

The problem is I can't calculate the total distance and duration of the whole trip. There are many "duration" and "distance" fields in this geoJSON.

Do I have to work with these multiple fields, or is there any other way to calculate the total distance and duration?

Comment: Just as tip, you are sharing here the API url but this contains your access token too.

Comment: @leonardfactory Thanks for the tip! I solved my problem following the Steve Bennett indications. Thank you too for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the distance and duration, just take `routes[0].distance` and `routes[0].duration` respectively.

(You don't want to add them up: these represent alternative routes, not parts of one long journey.)

See https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions-response-object .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`turf.js`](https://turfjs.org) library passing it the geoJSON and then do some spacial analysis.

The concept here is to pass a geoJSON feature to `turf` and use the `length` function:

```js
var geojson = /** get your shape from API */;
var length = turf.length(geojson, {units: 'kilometers'});
```

Here is an example directly from MapBox: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/

Edit:
since there is a `duration` and `distance` in the routes specified by mapbox api, you can process the `geojson.routes` object, like this:

```js
var duration = geojson.routes.reduce(
 (d, route) => d + route.duration
 0
);
```

This way you can even use the `route.distance` field in order the get the total distance.

EDIT n.2: **DON'T DO THIS!** I messed it up, routes is just an array of *alternatives*, kudos to Steve Bennet for pointing this out.